# Wrong Result in Computing the Laplacian

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, expression-manipulation

I am using Mathematica 11.0.1.0. I have the following simple code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

L[f_] := Laplacian[f, {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"]

B[f_] := Laplacian[
  Laplacian[f, {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"], {r, \[Theta], z}, 
  "Cylindrical"]

f = Subscript[A, 1] z^3 + 
    Inactive[Sum][(Subscript[P, i] Sinh[Subscript[\[Alpha], i] z] + 
    Subscript[Q, i] z Cosh[Subscript[\[Alpha], i] z]) BesselJ[0, 
    Subscript[\[Alpha], i] r], {i, 1, n}]

L[f]

(* 6 z Subscript[A, 1] *)

B[f]

(* 0 *)
```

The result that Mathematica is giving for the Laplacian is wrong. The true answer is

$$ 6A_1z + \sum_{i=1}^{n}2 Q_i \alpha_i \sinh(\alpha_iz) J_0(\alpha_i r)$$

However, when I remove the sum the true result can be obtained

```
f = Subscript[A, 1] z^3 + (Subscript[P, i] Sinh[Subscript[\[Alpha], i] z] + 
    Subscript[Q, i] z Cosh[Subscript[\[Alpha], i] z]) BesselJ[0, 
    Subscript[\[Alpha], i] r]

L[f] // FunctionExpand

(* 6 z Subscript[A, 1] + 
2 BesselJ[0, r Subscript[\[Alpha], i]] Sinh[
z Subscript[\[Alpha], i]] Subscript[Q, i] Subscript[\[Alpha], i] *)

B[f] // FunctionExpand

(* 0 *)
```

Can anyone help me with this and say what is going on here?

Comment: Can't reproduce your results in 11.1. However, it spits out some complicated outputs along with some error messages. I'm able to get the correct answers (not fully simplified) by replacing Inactive[Sum] with Sum.

Comment: I would suggest not using Sum at all.

Comment: @W.Mason: I am using 11.0 so I should do some updates maybe! :)

Comment: @W.Mason: See the updated question. I figured it out that how to obtain the correct result. It seems to be a bug in Mathematica 11!

Comment: Well, of course it works when you remove the Sum. It could be a bug with Inactive[Sum] in Mathematica, but Sum alone in 11.1 works OK (hard to simplify the answer unless I remove Sum). I think Sum should altogether be avoided in such calculations, at least until these problems are fixed.

Comment: Please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag to your *own* questions. Take a look at the tag description.

Comment: @Szabolcs: OK. Thanks for mentioning. :) But this is a bug! What should I do?

Comment: Hopefully, someone will put in the time to fully understand what is going on, confirm the bug, and add the tag along with the standard header. I can't do that now. I tried briefly in a fresh kernel with M11.1, and got a bunch or error messages instead of the result you cite.  Another thing: whenever you suspect a bug, add the full version info. The version number is made of *three* digits.

Comment: What you should do: if you are fully confident that there is a bug, report it to Wolfram. We here cannot do anything about it, but they can (but only if they are aware of the problem—so tell them!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug, plain and simple.  If you use Sum instead of Inactive[Sum], it works in both 11.0 and 11.1.

I'm pretty sure I know what was the bug in 11.0 and that I fixed that particular bug in 11.1.  Unfortunately, there now seems to be a bad interaction with our new indexed-differentiation code which is producing a different wrong answer in 11.1.  I will investigate and try to fix this for 11.2. If I come up with any more general workarounds, I will post them here.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the attention. :) I reported this bug. :)